# Integrate $\sin^5 x$

Tags: calculus, integration

I know $\sin x$ integrates to $-\cos x$ but ive never seen $\sin^5(x)$ integrated. 
would I need to expand it to $\sin x\sin x\sin x\sin x\sin x$ and then how would I complete the integration from here?

Comment: Hint: $\sin^5 x=(1-\cos^2 x)^2\sin x$.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\int \sin^5 x dx = \int(1-\cos^2x)^2\sin x dx =-\int (1-2\cos^2x + \cos^4 x) d\cos x$
Set $t=\cos x$ and integrate.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int \sin^5 x dx = \int (\sin^2 x)^2 \cdot \sin x dx = \int (1-\cos^2 x)^2 \sin x dx$$

Substutute $v = \cos x$, meaning $dv = -\sin x dx$ and you get
$$\int (1 - \cos ^2 x)^2 x \cdot \sin x dx = -\int (1-v^2)^2 dv.$$ Should be easier from here on.

Comment: as dv=-sinxdx where does the - go when you sub it in?

Comment: I missed it at first, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$\begin{align}\sin^5x&=(1/2i)^5(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})^5
 \\&={(-1/4)^2(e^{i2x}-2+e^{-i2x})}^2 (1/2i)(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})
 \\&=(1/16)(e^{i4x}+e^{-i4x}-4e^{i2x}-4e^{-i2x}+6)(1/2i)(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})
 \\&=(1/32i)(e^{i5x}-e^{i5x}-5e^{i3x}+5e^{-i3x}+10e^{ix}-10e^{-ix})
 \\&=(1/16)\sin5x-(5/16)\sin3x+(5/8)\sin x,\end{align}$$
you'll have
$$∫\sin^5 x dx =(-1/80)\cos5x+(5/48)\cos3x-(5/8)\cos x+C.$$

Comment: Wow you must be a math prof. The fact that the OP is asking this question leads me to believe she has not progressed far enough to make head or tails of this answer. It will be much easier for her to integrate ${(1-\cos^2\theta)^2\sin\theta d\theta}$

Comment: Yeah, I totally agree with your last sentence:) To be honest, this is what I first noticed...

Answer (score 0):

Here's another answer:
We know from using integration by parts that
$$
\int\sin^5x dx = -\frac{1}{5}\sin^4x\cos x + \frac{4}{5}\int\sin^3x dx
$$
Applying intgration by parts to $\int\sin^3xdx$ means
$$
\int\sin^5x dx = - \frac{1}{5}\sin^4x\cos x + \frac{4}{5}(-\frac{3}{4}\cos x + \frac{1}{12}\cos 3x)
$$
$$
= - \frac{1}{5}\sin^4x\cos x - \frac{3}{5}\cos x +\frac{1}{15}\cos 3x
$$
$$
= -\frac{1}{5}(\sin^2x)^2\cos x- \frac{3}{5}\cos x +\frac{1}{15}\cos 3x
$$
$$
= -\frac{1}{5}\cos x(1 - \cos^2 x)^2- \frac{3}{5}\cos x +\frac{1}{15}\cos 3x
$$
$$
= -\frac{1}{5}\cos x(1 - 2\cos^2 x + \cos^4 x) - \frac{3}{5}\cos x +\frac{1}{15}\cos 3x
$$
$$
= -\frac{1}{5}\cos x + \frac{2}{5}\cos^3 x - \frac{1}{5}\cos^5 x- \frac{3}{5}\cos x +\frac{1}{15}\cos 3x
$$
$$
= -\frac{1}{5}\cos x + \frac{2}{5}(\frac{3}{4}\cos x + \frac{1}{4}\cos 3x) - \frac{1}{5}(\frac{5}{8}\cos x + \frac{5}{16}\cos 3x + \frac{1}{16}\cos 5x) - \frac{3}{5}\cos x +\frac{1}{15}\cos 3x
$$
$$
= \cos x(-\frac{1}{40} - \frac{3}{5}) + \cos 3x(\frac{1}{15} + \frac{3}{80}) - \frac{1}{80}\cos 5x
$$
$$
= -\frac{5}{8}\cos x + \frac{5}{48}\cos 3x - \frac{1}{80}\cos 5x
$$
However, given I obtained this problem from Apostol "Calculus" Volume 1 Section 5.10 Question 10 (c) (Page 221) and the problem in Apostol states
$$
\int\sin^5x dx = -\frac{5}{8}x + \frac{5}{48}\cos 3x - \frac{1}{8}\cos 5x
$$
I can only assume that I found a typographical error in Apostol's epic tome! Hope this helps :-)